# Firefox 122 does not open custom schere URL

Tags: firefox

We have a product which opens with a custom scheme such as myapp://. But since FF 122 this does not work anymore and no errors are displayed in the browser console (Firebug F12 => console tab).
The release notes only mention *"The fallback URL parser for unknown schemes was changed to DefaultURI"* but I have no idea what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

about:config -> network.url.useDefaultURI -> false

Comment: Thanks, this did help for our environment. Do you happen to know any possibility to deploy this specific setting (preferably with register key)?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).